# C# Form Webbrowser click div

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, forms, browser

My webbrowser connects to a page, then I want it to click a div.

```
<div class="acceptButton state1">
      <a class="buttonGreen">
           <span>${$item.getAddressButtonText( $data.messageType )}</span>
      </a>
</div>
```

The page uses jquery or something to do it all. :( and most help I found required an id, which these only have a class

```
  <script id='messageListItem' type='text/x-jquery-template'>
<li data-messagetype="${messageType}" class="${messageType}" data-messageid="${messageId}">
    <div class="messageItem">
        <div class="closeButton">
            <a><span>X</span></a>
        </div>

        <img class="friendImage" src="${senderImgUrl}" alt="${senderName}" />

        <div class="messageBubble">
            <div class="messageBubbleTop"></div>
            <div class="messageBubbleBody">
                <div class="messageBubbleContent">
                    {{if $data.messageImgUrl != null}}
                    <img class="giftImage messageImage" alt="${messageImgAltText}" src="${messageImgUrl}">
                    {{/if}}
                    <h5 class="friendName">${senderName}:</h5>
                    <p class="requestMessage">${message}</p>
                    <span class="requestDate">${timestampStr}</span>
                    <div class="clearFloat"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="messageBubbleBottom"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="acceptButton state1">
            <a class="buttonGreen"><span>${$item.getAddressButtonText( $data.messageType )}</span></a>
        </div>

        <div class="clearFloat"></div>
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: what exactly is the problem ?

Comment: All code ive seen doesnt search classes, and the button im trying to click has like 10 similar, I cant even tell how the browser tells them apart

Comment: Im trying something like   HtmlElement link = webBrowser.Document.GetElementByID("buttonGreen")
link.InvokeMember("Click")

Comment: You want to click on that div right there? Is it static? Does it always exist? Can we traverse the dom to get to it? can I see the code starting at the nearest parent element that has an ID?

Comment: Instead of posting that in the comment, edit your original post, add the additional code, and use bold text to discern the 'Edit'. Also, if it's a METRIC CRAP TON of code, then please use an external hosting site and link to it, such as jsFiddle, or Pastebin.

Comment: It is always there, and it will change once that page executes it, but that is the source before its been changed. The source I get once it is changed is entirely different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To click the div you can run JavaScript code in the WebBrowser's DocumentCompleted event handler using `Navigate()`:

webBrowser1.Navigate("javascript: /* your javascript code */ void(0);");

So if you have a div:

```
<div class="myDivClass">
    ...
</div>
```

You can trigger a click on it using:

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("javascript: document.getElementsByClassName('myDivClass')[0].click();void(0);"); //assuming it's first and/or only div with that class
```

Comment: Well it is a <a class=""></a> type thing. With a span inside it.

Comment: @user1237570: Didn't it work? I'm pretty sure I tested that :-??

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, it is not possible to click a `DIV`. In that, if you try, the event in the `DIV` will not trigger. Say, if the `DIV`has an `onclick` event, it will not trigger.

So, what you have to do, in order to get the `onclick` event in the `DIV` to trigger, is to click anything (any of the other elements) in the `DIV`. Let's say the `DIV` has an `IMG` element/tag: Perform a `.click` on that and the `DIV`'s `onclick` event will be triggered. Does this make sense? So any `DIV`'s `onclick` triggering is only possible through `onclick` event bubbling - by using the method I described above.

I am just telling you this in case you we're expecting an `onclick` event to run that is attached directly to the `DIV`. Just in case you add it in the future or you run into it later, it is important for you to understand this (even though I didn't see an `onclick` in your `DIV`tag at the moment, it's an important information to have).

Hope this helps and if you have any further questions, let me know.

I only found this through testing and it isn't really written anywhere, the same thing applies to the `span` tag if I remember correctly.